# ajax call can't get error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hey I have an ajax call that I'm using which goes to a controller and ultimately makes a sql call. I'm using a deprecated version using `.success`

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/group/create",
                data: postData,
                context: this
            }).success(function(msg) {
                if (msg.errors) {
                    //showCreateGroupErrors(msg.errors);
                    this.setState({
                        error: true,
                        errorMsg: msg.errors[0]
                    });

                } else {
                    //showCreateGroupSuccess("Group successfully created!");
                    this.props.addGroup(this.state.familyName);
                    this.props.update();
                }
            });
```

The problem is whenever I get `sql syntax error` the sql request goes through but I don't get any type of error or call back time deal that I can latch on to and print through console or what ever. Any Ideas?

Usually it would be carried in the `msg` object above but in my test cases it just circumvents the `.success` function. Not sure whats going on.

Comment: It depends on how the back end handles the error. You should probably start on the other end.

Comment: You should show how the `create` method is defined.